# How do I access things inside a 2D array and also update a node?

Tags: python

This is the code that I'm using.

I cannot seem to get my head around how I should go around to get the numbers inside the "network" list and use the numbers so I can calculate Djikstra's algorithm. Also, right at the bottom, there's a code that is commented, I'm also trying to find out how to update a node but can't get it to work :/.

Also I am using python 2.7.8

Any help would be appreciated.

```
infinity = 1000000
invalid_node = -1

class Node:
previous = invalid_node
distFromSource = infinity
visited = False

def populateNetwork(fileName):

    network = []
    networkFile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in networkFile:
        network.append(map(int, line.strip().split(',')))
    return network

def populateNodeTable(network, StartNode):
    nodeTable = []
    for node in network:
        nodeTable.append(Node())
    nodeTable[StartNode].distFromSource = 0
    nodeTable[StartNode].visited = True
    return nodeTable

network = populateNetwork('network.txt')
nodeTable = populateNodeTable(network, 1)


for node in nodeTable:
    print node.previous, node.distFromSource, node.visited

for line in network:
    print line

for index, val in enumerate(network):
    print index, val


#for node in nodeTable:
    #nodeTable.append(populateNodeTable(network,2))
    #print node.previous, node.distFromSource, node.visited
    #break
```

Text Ouput:

```
-1 1000000 False
-1 0 True
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
[0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5]
[0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
0 [0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0]
1 [2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
2 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]
3 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
4 [6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5]
5 [0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0, 0]
6 [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
```

Edit: Text output included

Comment: Please include the output here in your question instead of linking to it. Also, what does "can't get it to work" mean? Are you getting exceptions? If so, include the entire traceback here. Are you getting bad results? What are they and what did you expect?

Comment: Recommendation: edit your question to include the (text) output. You can copy and paste it from your terminal, and then remove the link to a screenshot of the text.

Comment: @skrrgwasme No error or anything, It's just wrong output and I have no clue why.Here's the output -1 1000000 False
-1 0 True
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
[0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5]
[0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
0 [0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0]
1 [2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
2 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]
3 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
4 [6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5]
5 [0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0, 0]
6 [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
-1 1000000 False

Comment: @Skrrgwasme im getting a -1 1000000 false at the end when I should be getting an update of the node output with 2 true